# "Disjoint" elements of a lattice - what's the correct terminology?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

Given a set $X$ and a pair of subsets thereof, call them $A$ and $B$, we say that $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint* iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$. This generalizes to lattices with a least element. Given such a lattice $L$ and a pair of elements thereof, call them $a$ and $b$, we can say that $a$ and $b$ are "disjoint" iff $a \wedge b = \bot$. For instance, in the lattice induced by the divisibility relation $|$ on $\mathbb{N}$, we have that $1$ (not $0$) is the least element (since $1$ divides everything), that $a \wedge b$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and that $a$ and $b$ are "disjoint" iff they're relatively prime.

What's the technical correct term for "disjoint" elements of a lattice with a least element?

Comment: I think *disjoint* is the right term.

Comment: "disjoint" is good.  Sometimes the symbol $A\perp B$ is used, then it might read as "orthogonal".

Comment: Sometimes $a$ is called a semi-complement of $b$.

Comment: We also say "a and b meet at zero."